# Send message to a particlular server with its id - discord.py

Tags: discord.py

How i can send messages to a **custom server** with its **id** using discord.py bot on discord. i trying a lot to find a way of it. So can anyone tell that does it possible to send messages to a particular server or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `discord.utils.get` for this. here is an example:

```
custom_guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, id='guild id')
```

then if you want, you can get a channel from `custom_guild` with also `discord.utils.get` like this:

```
custom_channel = discord.utils.get(custom.guild.channels, id="channel id")
```

The rest of it is simple. You just have to do `await custom_channel.send('Hey')`.

Comment: @Nurque error - Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'

Comment: Sorry my fault, change the `custom.guild.channels` as `custom_guild.channels`

Comment: And when you ask a question and if you receive an answer that solves your question, you should accept it as an answer so if someone got this problem, they can easily find the solution.

Comment: Remove the `" "` and `' '` just leave the id.